# Pasting into a textbox breaks back end email construction

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm having the oddest issue that I can't even rationalize.
I have a form with several textboxes, one of which is the comments box:

MVC:

```
<div class="contactUsTextArea">
    Comments or Questions:<br />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments, new { maxlength = 990 } )
</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="contactUsTextArea">
    Comments or Questions:
    <br>
    <textarea id="Comments" rows="2" name="Comments" maxlength="990" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

When the forms is submitted, this code runs:

```
public bool SendEmail(ContactUsModel formSubmission) {
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    string upc = formSubmission.ProductUpcCode;
    string comments = formSubmission.Comments;
    string comments_small = formSubmission.Comments;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formSubmission.ProductUpcCode) && upc.Length > 14 )
        upc = upc.Substring(0, 13);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comments) && comments.Length > 990)
        comments = comments.Substring(0, 989);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comments_small) && comments_small.Length > 255)
        comments_small = comments_small.Substring(0, 254);

    string bodyText = "FIRST_NAME:" + formSubmission.FirstName + "\n" +
                        "LAST_NAME:" + formSubmission.LastName + "\n" +
                        "COMPANY:" + formSubmission.CompanyName + "\n" +
                        "ADDRESS:" + formSubmission.StreetAddress + "\n" +
                        "CITY_TOWN:" + formSubmission.City + "\n" +
                        "STATE_PROVINCE:" + formSubmission.Province + "\n" +
                        "ZIP_POSTAL:" + formSubmission.PostalCode + "\n" +
                        "COUNTRY:CAN\n" +
                        "EMAIL:" + formSubmission.Email + "\n" +
                        "PHONE:" + formSubmission.PhoneNumber + "\n" +
                        "UPC:" + upc + "\n" +
                        "DATE_CODE:\n" +
                        "BRAND_PRODUCT:" + formSubmission.ProductName + "\n" +
                        "COMMENTS:" + comments_small + "\n" +
                        "FULL_COMMENTS:" + comments + "\n" +
                        "LANGUAGE:English" + "\n" +
                        "OPTIN:N";
    email.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSubmission_FROM"]);
    email.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSubmission_TO"]));
    email.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSubmission_SUBJECT"];
    email.IsBodyHtml = false;
    email.Body = bodyText;
    email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    smtp.Send(email);            
    return true;
}
```

(Don't ask me why I need a small comments and large comments, clients will be clients)

Anyway, my issue is when I type a comment into the comment box I get this return:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVMVa.png

However when I copy paste text I get this return:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C1Se.png

Why is this happening?

Comment: Language and Optin should be on their own lines... what happened to the '\n'

Comment: Raw view on an none html email?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the BodyEncoding?

Comment: Ref the raw view; drag the email into Notepad

Comment: Commenting out the body encoding didn't change anything.

Comment: have you debugged your code and paused it to see what's in comments?

Comment: and are you pasting exactly the same text as you're typing?

Comment: I've stepped through my code in debug and the VS Viewer for the string always looks the same (and proper).

Comment: Other than having your script send the email to alternative clients to test those, i'm at a loss on this one..sorry :/

Comment: I figured it out Darren... see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... so I'll just post a picture of what my issue was... and then I'm going to go hide in shame in a cave forever.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTccm.png

Thanks for the help though everyone.

Comment: LOL :D An idea for next time though; do the tests with the same data. I think some of us (me anyway) assumed that the writing in your first image was being substituted for the text in your second image.

Comment: So actually, my answer was correct then. I told you it was something related to the client >:|

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few things that this could be (that I could think of) - both of which are related to the client.

- Something with the email client where its not rendering the `\n` like it should.
  Although for Windows, `\r\n` is the standard, and many applications dont honor '`\n`' properly. I would try using that for newlines instead of just `\n`.
- Also something with the client, related to encoding (but i doubt it)